# Send email to specific people based on cell drop down

Tags: google-apps-script

I hope someone can help as I'm a novice with all this.

I have a google sheet that my staff will fill out to confirm they have read a brief that has been sent out and there are 2 drop down options (added through 'data validation) one says 'I have a read and understand' the other says 'I do not understand can I get some more info please?' if the colleague selects the latter I would like an automatic email to be sent to a specific person.

How would I go about this please?

Has someone got a code I could use please? I've tried all sorts of codes on similar threads on here and I just keep getting error messages.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: You could use a installable onEdit trigger.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you validate cell is in A1 of "Brief Sheet" ie `e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1` is A1

```
function briefReadResponse(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Brief Sheet" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1) {
    if(e.value == "I understand") {
      //do something
    } else {
      sendEmail(e);
    }
  }
}
```